# How do I generate a comma-separated list with XSLT

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, xpath

Im trying to import a XML with a XSLT in ms access so that it imports with the list as comma separated
My XML:

```
<entry>
    <title>Adobe</title>
    <description>Adobe Acrobat</description>
    <title>Adobe1</title>
    <description>Adobe Acrobat1</description>
    <title>Adobe2</title>
    <description>Adobe Acrobat2</description>
</entry>
```

My attempt:

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Expected results:   Adobe, Adobe1, Adobe2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML only has one `entry`, so the code within the `xsl:for-each` will only run once. And doing `<xsl:value-of select="title" />` will only select the first `title` within that `entry` (Assuming XSLT 1.0, that is)

Change it to this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry/title">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that in XSTL 2.0, you could replace the above code snippet entirely with this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="entry/title" separator="," />
```

EDIT: Suppose your XSLT looks like this...

```
<iavmNotice xmlns="http://stuff.com" noticeId="138643">
   <title>Cisco Vulnerability</title>
   <techOverview>
      <entry>
         <title>2012-2490</title>
         <description>Cisco ID 71.</description>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <title>2012-2525</title>
         <description>Cisco ID 69.</description>
      </entry>
   </techOverview>
</iavmNotice>
```

Then, to use `xsl:for-each` in context, you would add a template like so:

```
<xsl:template match="stuff:techOverview">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="stuff:entry/stuff:title">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Do note the following:

- Ensure the `stuff` prefix is bound to the correct namespace as per the input XML
- Ensure you have no other templates matching `stuff:techOverview`

Comment: Thank you for the answer Tim! But where in my xsl would I put that snippet?

Comment: @jjohnson: I can maybe help with your new question, but it is not good practise to edit a question after it has been answered with a radically different version of the question, as it means the original answer no longer makes sense. The original answer may not have helped you, but it may have helped other people (2 people upvoted my answer). I have rolled back the edit to your question. Instead you should ask a new question, but give some thought about how you present your question. Show the input XML, the XSLT you have tried, and the output you expect that corresponds to the input. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC FYI, I have closed at least two of OP's attempts to post this as a new question, because I believe it's the same question, with the same answer. It only needs a few more location steps in the expression selecting the `title` + a prefix for the namespace.

Comment: @jjohnson - I've amended my answer to try and put it more in context, based on the XML you showed in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036085/rename-a-xml-element-and-comma-seperate-with-xslt).