# Rename a XML element and comma seperate with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What I want to do is rename iavmNotice/title to iavmNotice/iavmTitle:
Here is my XML:

```
<iavmNotice xmlns="http://stuff.com" noticeId="138643">
   <title>Cisco Vulnerability</title>
   <techOverview>
      <entry>
         <title>2012-2490</title>
         <description>Cisco ID 71.</description>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <title>2012-2525</title>
         <description>Cisco ID 69.</description>
      </entry>
   </techOverview>
</iavmNotice>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="iavmNotice/title">
   <iavmTitle>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </iavmTitle>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@iavmNotice/title">
  <xsl:attribute name="iavmTitle">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Also as a bonus is there a way to import techOverview/entry/title as comma separated? Import it as 2012-2490, 2012-2525 and remove description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xmlns="http://stuff.com"` declaration on the `iavmNotice` root element of the XML document puts the entire document into the `http://stuff.com` namespace.

So you either need to make your stylesheet aware of that namespace, or else on your matches just use `local-name()`:

```xslt
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'iavmNotice']/*[local-name() = 'title']">
     <iavmTitle>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </iavmTitle>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much! Now is there a way to import techOverview/entry/title as comma separated? Import it as 2012-2490, 2012-2525 and remove description

Comment: You probably get better luck with that if you post it as a separate question with a specific title that describes the problem